# JavaScript deep spread operator on deep arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a deep array, hence the array with arrays children like below:

```
const deepArray = ['1',[['a'],['b']],[2],[[[['4',[3,'c']]]],[5]]];
```

I wanna set all end children in a flat array, I use `spread operator` of `ES6` but it spread shallow, I have no idea to how to make them to below:

```
const shallowArray = ['1','a','b',2,'4',3,'c',5];
```

Maybe a recursive function can do it but how? it should be very optimized because I wanna use it in a `react native` project. I'm worried about crash so I'm very cautious about optimization.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030117/8269581 helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array, then use the spread operator as needed.

If you know the arrays depth or max size of depth, use the following code:

```
const flatArray = deepArray.flat(7); // assume you know depth size is 7
```

If you don't know the depth, you can use a recursive method that using `reduce` function, use below:

```
 const deepFlatten = arr =>
         arr.reduce(
           (acc, val) =>
             Array.isArray(val) 
               ? acc.concat(deepFlatten(val)) 
               : acc.concat(val),
             []
         );
```

Use above function to flat undeterminate depth:

```
const flatArray = deepFlatten(deepArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using recursion, its pretty straightforward :)

```js
let deepArray = ['1',[['a'],['b']],[2],[[[['4',[3,'c']]]],[5]]];
let array = [];
 
function f(d){
    Array.isArray(d)? d.forEach(x=> f(x)) : array.push(d);   
}
    
deepArray.forEach(x=>f(x));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I want a flatten function for `react-native` merge styles. because in `react-native` sometimes you have a deep array of styles and it is essential to flat them.

But I find out the `react-native` `StyleSheet` have a good and optimized `flatten` function for handling this problem.

If someone read my question and need to handle deep arrays of style use below code:

```
const styleJoiner = (...arg) => StyleSheet.flatten(arg);
```